# cannot close RootViewController

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller

In Xcode 4 I've created a SplitView project, so I have a DetailViewController and a RootViewController.

In RootViewController's viewDidLoad(), I have added a cancel button on the left side like this

```
// add a cancel button on the left side
cancelButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                                                             target:self action:@selector(cancelAction:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
```

When the RootViewController is displayed and I click on the cancel button, I want to close the RootViewController. In my cancelButton handler I've tried calling

```
#if 0
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
#else   
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
#endif
```

but neither one of them work for me. I've tried googling for hours but have still not found a solution.

Can someone please tell me how to close the RootViewController?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to close popover of RootViewController in portrait orientation because in landscape it doesn't make sense.

You can do it like this:

1) cancel button handler:

```
-(void)cancelAction {
    [self.detailViewController.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

2) popoverController is private in detailViewController so you must make it public (or add method to detailview that will have access to popoverController property and call this method from cancelAction in RootViewController):

2.1) delete

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
```

from

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
...
@end
```

2.2) add

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
```

inside

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
```